# DropDownListFor display box is blank after selection

Tags: html, model-view-controller, dropdownlistfor

**Problem:**

Hello I'm having troubles all of a sudden with my DropDownListFor which was working just fine. I was styling my web app a bit but didn't change anything on dropdownlistfor

```
 <!-- Genre -->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Genre)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, new SelectList(Model.Genres.OrderBy(n=>n.Name), "Id", "Name"), "Select Genre", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Genre)
    </div>
```

And in Controller

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var viewModel = new GigFormViewModel
        {
            Genres = _context.Genres.ToList()
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Okay so, here's the visual of my problem:

[Blank display box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQOJf.png)

[Yet the item is selected and will save properly to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5rCr.jpg)

So it's just visual thing that bothers me..saving and everything else is working just fine.

I even inspected element and color of the items are black tried to change background of display box in case font is white so I can see it but nope, the selection just does not display at all.

Edit: Viewmodel ->

```
 public class GigFormViewModel
{

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Venue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [FutureDate]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ValidTime]
    public string Time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Genre { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public DateTime GetDateTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time));
    }
```

And Genre class

```
 public class Genre
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this change

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, new SelectList(Model.Genres.OrderBy(n=>n.Name), "Id", "Name",0), "Select Genre", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

may be it will work for you..;)

Comment: Nope unfortunately It doesn't. I've already tried that and with different values, like 1 and 2..yet the problem remains the same.

Comment: Ohh..then something is going wrong..have u tried with text instead of value..please try to putting "Select Genre" instead of 0. i am not sure..bt have u tried like this

Comment: Nope that won't work I'm sure. Edit: tried it anyway and it didn't, also edited my post to include my viewmodel